# Splunk - Rest API - Curl - Failing with Unbalanced Quotes

Tags: rest, curl, splunk

I'm trying to write data to outputlookup file by doing a REST API Call (by running a search query).

The below command works and writes data to outputlookup csv file when running the search directly from Splunk.

```
**| stats count as field1 | eval field1="host_abc;host_def" 
| eval field1=split(field1,";") 
| mvexpand field1 | rex field=field1 "(?<host>.*)" 
| table host | outputlookup test_maintenance.csv**
```

But this is not working when executing the above search using REST API.

**Getting the below error "Unbalanced quotes" when running the below command**

```
curl -k -u admin:admin https://splunksearchnode:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/jobs/export -d search="| stats count as field1 | eval field1=\"host_abc;host_def\" | eval field1=split(field1,\";\") | mvexpand field1 | rex field=field1 \"(?<host>.*)\" | table host | outputlookup test_maintenance.csv"
```

Getting the below error  when running the below command

Error : Error in 'EvalCommand': The expression is malformed. An unexpected character is reached at ''host_abc'.

```
curl -k -u admin:admin https://splunksearchnode:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/jobs/export -d search='| stats count as field1 | eval field1=\"host_abc;host_def\" | eval field1=split(field1,\";\") | mvexpand field1 | rex field=field1 \"(?<host>.*)\" | table host | outputlookup test_maintenance.csv'
```

Comment: Not a curl expert, but the issue might be that you wrap you search within `"..."` and then also within the search use `"..."` during your eval statement. Try escaping the quotation marks within the query!

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding the query in the curl commands?